# Raspberry Pi v4, forced VSYNC?

Tags: sdl

I wrote an emulator and I have a piece of code that syncs audio/video using elapsed time and remaining bytes to play on audio buffer. This works very well.

If I remove that piece of code emulator runs as fast as it can on x86 Ubuntu laptop, i.e. over 200 FPS. On Raspberry Pi v4 I can't go over 60 FPS (for some games stucks at 30 FPS) like an hardware VERTICAL SYNC is enabled.

I use SDL2 and I don't use **SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC** when create the renderer.

So, the problem is not a piece of code, and now the synchronization code is commented out, the problem is:

**"Why WITHOUT that code Raspberry Pi 4 stucks on 60 FPS?"**

SDL2 built from 2.0.14 source code with

```
--disable-video-rpi --enable-video-kmsdrm
```

Test with Raspberry Pi v4 Kernel 5.4 and Kernel 5.10 with `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` or `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d`.

Monitor set to 1080p at 60 Hz.

PS: Raspberry Pi v3 goes over 60 FPS without any problem